# Length of text in Column Headings in Interactive Grid

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I require column headings to be as wide as text length in an Interactive Grid. In my report, which columns will get displayed depend on what user will choose in a select list using server-side conditions.

Is there any way to implement that?

Screenshot:

[image]

What Columns need to be displayed depend on the value chosen by the user through DQ Audit Select List.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't trivial, but the following should work for you...

First, add the following function to the page's **Function and Global Variable Declaration** property:

```
function resizeIGColumns(gridView) {
  var addWidth = 20;
  var addWidthSort = 2;

  gridView.view$.grid('getColumns').forEach(function(column) {
    if (column.hidden || column.property === 'APEX$ROW_ACTION') {
      return true;
    }

    var headerSpan$ = $('#' + column.domId);
    var headerSort$ = headerSpan$.next('.a-GV-header-sort');\
    var width = headerSpan$.width() + addWidth;

    if (headerSort$.length) {
      width += headerSort$.width() + addWidthSort;
    }

    gridView.view$.grid('setColumnWidth', column.property, width);
  });
}
```

Next, add the following code to the page's **Execute when Page Loads** attribute:

```
var gridView = apex.region('emp-reg').call('getViews').grid;
var widgetInst = gridView.view$.data('apex-grid');
var orgRefresh = widgetInst.refresh;

widgetInst.refresh = function() {
  orgRefresh.call(widgetInst);
  resizeIGColumns(gridView);
};

widgetInst.refresh();
```

This code is redefining the refresh function of the grid widget so that it invokes an additional `resizeIGColumns` function.

**Older versions of APEX**

After meeting with Abhinav online, we found that the following lines needed to be changed in APEX 5.

In `resizeIGColumns`, this line:

```
var headerSpan$ = $('#' + column.domId);
```

Should be changed to this:

```
var headerSpan$ = $('#' + column.elementId + '_HDR');
```

And in the **Execute When Page Loads** code, this line:

```
var gridView = apex.region('emp-reg').call('getViews').grid;
```

Should be changed to this:

```
var gridView = apex.region('emp-reg').widget().interactiveGrid('getViews').grid;
```

Comment: Do I need to plug in my own values in var gridView and widgetInst instead of 'emp-reg' and 'apex-grid'?

Comment: Sorry, yes. First assign the region a Static ID. Then use that value instead of emp-reg.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I am still getting '...' in the Column headings, which I don't want.

Comment: In all of them? Could you add a screenshot to your question?

Comment: I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Interesting. See the addWidth variable? Try making that higher. Experiment with a few different values.

Comment: Javascript code is running on the landing page, but doesn't run after page refreshe upon clicking Submit button.

Comment: Seems like there are two issues: 1) The ellipses shown on each column (did you have any luck with adjusting `addWidth`?) 2) The JavaScript isn't running more than once. I created this solution on apex.oracle.com (which runs APEX 20.1 at the moment). I just noticed you're running APEX 5.1, which is quite dated at this point. Would you consider upgrading? You'll get lots of other bug fixes and enhancements! :)

Comment: 1. Nope. Didn't have any luck with adjusting addWidth varaible. 2. I believe so as well, as your script is running fine on the default screen when the page is loaded. However, I can't upgrade as that decision lies with people higher than my pay scale.

Comment: Seems like we will not get much further here as I don't have access to an APEX 5 instance. If you'd like to meet online so that I can see the app and offer suggestions, please DM me on Twitter (https://twitter.com/dmcghan) or contact me via my blog (https://jsao.io/contact/). If you do reach out, please include the URL to this Stack Overflow question.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to define the width of the columns:

1. Automatically. Depending on the number of columns in your IG, it will define the width column.

   2. By setting. You can go to *Actions -> Columns* and define the *Minimum Column Width (Pixel)* for every column.

Can you please set the width of the column and let me know if that works for you?

Comment: My report columns depend on the value chosen by a user through a select list. Setting of Column width works well for one report, but causes other reports to have weird column widths.